# why is a "Dynamic User" appearing in my "Users"?

Tags: login, users

A "Dynamic User" is showing up in my newly installed Ubuntu 18.04. This user doesn't appear in the /etc/passwd nor is there a /home/.

If I log out or power off the machine, when re-booting the "Dynamic User" isn't an option on the login screen, however if I'm logged in and the "Dynamic User" account is present then logging out of my account shows the "Dynamic User" as an option to log in under.

I don't see any activity in syslogs, if I run `sudo ac -p` it only shows my account. There is no entry in `auth.log` of "Dynamic User" nor is there a entry for last logged in, see screenshot.

I've not used Ubuntu for a while and perhaps this is some kind of "feature" related to "Ubuntu One"?

[Screen shot of "Dynamic User" in settings > Details > Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmblQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a new thing with GNOME 3.28.  I think its for a "Guest" user.  I recall reading a bit back somewhere about this feature.  Anything done in this account is NOT persistent.  So browser stuff, ssl keys, etc are not kept.

I am on my mobile killing time waiting so I could be wrong.  But I am rather confident this is what you are referencing.

Comment: Hi @andrew-schott - Thanks for the hint. I've not been able to search for any docs that mention this "feature" just yet. If you're able to track something down please link it when you can. Thanks again!